# Почему в Swift нельзя прибавить значение типа UInt8 к Int?

Tags: swift

Максимальное число UInt8 равно 255, значит мы никогда не присвоим значение больше чем может вместить Int. Следовательно почему для того чтобы это сделать нам необходимо обязательно менять тип UInt8 в Int?

Пример того что я хочу сделать на языке Swift:

```
let value_UInt8: UInt8 = 5
var value_Int: Int = 5
value_Int += value_UInt8 // Error Replace 'value_UInt8' with 'Int(value_UInt8)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift - язык с `сильной` `статической` типизацией. Это значит, что нельзя смешивать различные типы, так как не выполняются автоматические неявные преобразования.

`UInt8` и `Int` - разные типы, соответственно, преобразования нужно выполнять явно.

---

Теоретически конечно же можно всё. Ближайший аналог по Вашему примеру – ограниченное неявное приведение типов в Java:

```
byte a = 1; // Swift Int8.
int b = 1000;
int c = a + b; // Допустимо
byte d = a + b; // Недопустимо.
```

В случае `int c = a + b` byte никак не может выйти за пределы int, соответственно, здесь неявно приводится и получаем сумму int и byte.
В случае же `byte d = a + b` int выходит за пределы byte и как поступить в этом случае? Отбросить лишнее и оставить 128? Упасть программе во время исполнения? Отбросить "лишние" биты? Все это очень плохо и дополнительный источник ошибок. Поэтому решение этой ситуации возлагается на пишущего программу.

В Python, к примеру, можно умножить массив на число:

```
[1, 2] * 3 // Получим [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

Насколько это логично? Ну кому как.

Существуют языки в которых есть неявное приведение между всеми типами. Но страшно представить сколько это влечет за собой источников ошибок.

В общем, у каждого языка свои особенности. Но чем больше свободы дает сам язык – тем больше возможных источников ошибок и сложнее поддерживать написанное в будущем.

Comment: Это очевидно, но вопрос заключается гораздо глубже. Можем ли мы вообще теоретически сложить их? К примеру, существует ли такая возможность в других языках? Возможно ли это на машинном уровне в принципе?

Comment: @МаксимЗапорожец , обновил ответ.

Comment: Процессор так не умеет. А компиляторы языка c++ в таких случаях ставят неявное привидение и даже не предупреждают об этом.

Answer (score 0):

Разрядность int больше 8-ми бит, разрядность uint8_t ровно 8 бит. А где процессору брать недостающие биты для сложения? Поэтому **формально** так делать нельзя. А как можно? Можно сначала привести оба слагаемых к одному типу, а потом уже складывать. Будет приведение явным или неявным – вопрос отдельный. Если компилятор ругается, то успокойте его явным привидением.